# Kill process on specific port

Tags: process, kill, openbsd

It has been asked before but how to do it with OpenBSD? I tried some different method but none worked.

```
$ sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
fuser: 80/tcp: No such file or directory
$ kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:80)  
sudo: lsof: command not found
usage: kill [-s signame | -signum | -signame] { job | pid | pgrp } ...
       kill -l [exit_status ...]
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [fstat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/fstat.1) and [lsof](http://openports.se/sysutils/lsof) from ports / [packages](ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.8/packages/amd64).

## Installing lsof (PKG_PATH depends on your OS version):

```
$ su - root -c \
    "PKG_PATH=ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.8/packages/amd64 pkg_add -r lsof"
lsof-4.88: ok
```

## Using `fstat`:

```
# Start a process (nc) that listens on port 8080
$ nc -l 8080 & bg
[1] 17454
[1] nc -l 8080

# Get the process listening on port 8080:
$ fstat | grep :8080
cmihai   nc         17454    3* internet stream tcp 0x0 *:8080
```

We can create a function to get the pid, like this:

```
$ portpid() { fstat | grep ":$1" | awk '{print $3}' ;}
$ portpid 8080
17454
```

Then, we can kill a process listening on port 8080, like this:

```
$ kill $(portpid 8080)
[1] + Terminated           nc -l 8080
```

## Disclaimer:

- There is NO error handling or anything in this example - and I didn't do any kind of testing beyond the example listed here. Do test this yourself and add some error handling to that function to avoid killing another process by mistake.

## Reference:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/openbsd-list-open-tcp-or-udp-ports/